# Covering a Riemannian manifold with geodesic balls without too much overlap

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for a proof of the following fact:

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. There is a natural number $h$, such that for any sufficiently small number $r>0$, there exists a cover of $M$ by geodesic balls of radius $r$ such that any $h$ of the balls have empty intersection.

Comment: This can't be true as stated, because some of the balls must intersect by Hausdorff dimension arguments. Is it that there exist $h$ disjoint balls?

Comment: If we just look at the open manifold $\mathbb{R}^2$, and cover it by Euclidean balls, then certainly $h=4$ works for balls of arbitrary radius. So I'm very curious to see how your argument disproves the question. Would you mind posting it in more details as an answer?

Comment: No, I just misunderstood the question. Thanks!

Comment: No worries- thanks for the comments anyways!

Comment: Have you tried using the Gromov Packing Lemma? See, e.g., http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127934/upper-bound-on-covering-multiplicity

Answer (score 3):

There is a neighborhood about each point where the exponential map is bilipschitz with constants arbitrarily close to 1. This implies that the images of balls of radius $R$ under the exponential map are almost balls of radius $R$, i.e. they contain balls of radius, say, $3R/4$ and lie in balls of radius $5R/4$. Cover your space with finitely many such neighborhoods.

Take a uniform cubical lattice in $R^n$ such that the $r$-neighborhood of the lattice points covers $R^n$ and send it to each of the chosen neighborhoods via the exponential map. The balls of radius $4r/3$ about the images of the lattice points cover the manifold and intersect only a bounded number of balls from points coming from the same exponential map. (Note the bound does not depend on r). But each point is only in finitely many images of the exponential map, so there is a fixed number on how many balls of radius $4r/3$ can contain any point, which gives a bound on the number that can intersect.

This is rough, but I feel confident in it, let me know what you think.

TL;DR the number of neighborhoods in the cover is finite by compactness, and each point only intersects a bounded number of balls in each cover because a Riemannian metric is Bilipschitz eq. to the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Yes, the constant has to depend on n, but n is just the dimension of the manifold, which is fixed here. BTW, Are you the real PNB,or an impostor?

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood you. Your right, I just pulled the constant out of nowhere. But there exists a constant that works, And that is all we need.

Comment: I altered the answer. You will see that the 4/3 is used only as an arbitrary number independent of dimension that allows a little wiggle room in the metric.